# Attach to container on remote host with vscode

Tags: vscode-remote

In order to have sufficient computational power for my data science workflow, I'm using Docker containers on a remote machine. While I can connect via vscode-remote to my remote machine, I then can't attach to Docker containers running on this machine. Is there a way to do that? Or is this a feature not yet implemented?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using VSCode remote to connect to and develop in a remote container is supported, but it is considered an 'advanced' use of the 'Remote - Containers' functionality.  (The primary use cases currently include connecting to a remote VM via SSH and connecting to a local container.)

See here for instructions:
[Developing inside a container on a remote Docker host](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_developing-inside-a-container-on-a-remote-docker-host)

> Sometimes you may want to use the Remote - Containers extension to
>   develop inside a container that sits on remote server. This section
>   outlines how you can achieve this by using devcontainer.json or
>   attaching to an existing remote container...

Comment: Can't believe I missed the page during my search. I'm now using ssh forwarding to connect to the remote docker. It did not work with vs code stable 1.36, I always lost connection after a few seconds. For me, it works with the insider version (1.37). Thanks Tom!